# jblas android error

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have jblas 1.0.2 and there is this error:

```
The library 'jblas-1.2.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity] Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application because of their location in lib/
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity] lib/ is reserved for NDK libraries.
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity] The following libraries were found:
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Mac OS X/x86_64/libjblas_arch_flavor.jnilib
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Mac OS X/x86_64/sse3/libjblas.jnilib
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Linux/i386/sse2/libjblas.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Linux/i386/sse3/libjblas.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Linux/i386/libjblas_arch_flavor.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Linux/amd64/sse2/libjblas.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Linux/amd64/sse3/libjblas.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/static/Linux/amd64/libjblas_arch_flavor.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/dynamic/Linux/amd64/sse3/libjblas.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity]  - lib/dynamic/Linux/amd64/libjblas_arch_flavor.so
[2012-11-20 17:37:36 - com.hexar.filebroswer.activities.FileBroswerActivity] Unknown error: org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException
```

I only use the `FloatMatrix` and eigen vectors classes.

Do I have to install NDK? Will there be some problem in the future with stability?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of jblas you use is not compiled for Android. Look at the different paths the error complains about: they're all named "Mac OS X/something", or "Linux/i386/something" etc...

After a quick look on jblas.org, there is apparently no pre-compiled version available for Android at the moment:

> There exists a prepackaged jar-file with prebuild native libraries. Currently, Linux (i386/amd64), Mac OS X (i386/x86_64) and Windows (i386) are covered. Currently, only limited support for amd64 on Windows (full functionality, but not the same performance).